# C# Cannot access a closed stream while copying GZipStream to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, memorystream, gzipstream

I've been trying to convert a GZipStream into a MemoryStream and then convert it to a byte array without having to write any files to the hard drive. I've been trying to copy it to a MemoryStream but I've been getting this error: Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

I've looked at some of the other solutions, but I haven't been able to successfully implement them into what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
GZipStream decompressedStream = Decompress(new FileInfo(args[0]));
        using (var finalStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            decompressedStream.CopyTo(finalStream);
            byte[] decompressedBytes = new byte[finalStream.Length];
        }
```

EDIT: Somebody wanted me to add the code for Decompress() so here it is

```
public static GZipStream Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
    {
        using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
        {
            string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
            string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length) + " (decompressed)";
            using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
            {
                using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    return decompressionStream;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a decompressedStream.Close() ? also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253975/can-i-get-a-gzipstream-for-a-file-without-writing-to-intermediate-temporary-stor

Comment: Can you explain `Decompress`. Is it a function that return `GZipStream`? If yes, add it's code.

Comment: @Hamid Reza Mohammadi Yes I'll add the decompress function to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
     return decompressionStream;
}
```

`using` statement (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) article) disposes the stream and you can't use it outside of the block. Move your `MemoryStream` handling inside this block and return `byte[]` from the method.

Something like this should work:

```
public static byte[] Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
{
    using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
    {
        string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
        string newFileName = currentFileName.Remove(currentFileName.Length - fileToDecompress.Extension.Length) + " (decompressed)";
        using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
        {
            using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            using (var finalStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(finalStream);
                return finalStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```